# Emacs lisp function to count the difference between two times

Tags: elisp, parse-time

I would like to write an Emacs lisp function, that I can bind to a key shortcut. It will read in the two previous time entries in the format HHMM from the buffer and spit out the difference between them in the format 0.75, that is 45 minutes.

This is the format it should operate with.

```
1400 Enable ftp access for Sarah
1430   
.5
```

1. find the previous instance of HHMM in this buffer, occurs at the beginning of a line, and then find the one before that
2. determine the difference between the two times
3. output in hours with decimal fractions instead of minutes

**Pseudo code**

```
$end-time      = (search back from pointer for previous instance of HHMM)
$begin-time    = (search for second previous instance of HHMM)

$end-hour      = $end-time[0,1]
$end-minute    = $end-time[2,3]

$begin-hour    = $begin-time[0,1]
$begin-minute  = $begin-time[2,3]

$total-hours   = $end-hour - $begin-hour
$total-minutes = $end-minutes - $begin-minutes

return $total-hours + ($total-minutes * 0.01666666667)
```

Comment: See (elisp)[`Time of Day`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html), (elisp)[`Time Conversion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Conversion.html), and (elisp)[`Time Parsing`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html).

Comment: So far I just have made a ruby/pseudocode of what I would like to achieve

Comment: I haven't written a lisp function before

Comment: adding pseudo code to the question now. how should I approach this with Emacs?

Comment: @CharleyRamm: We do not cater to elisp snippet requests on this site. It happens that I got interested in writing a regexp for this problem and thus the below answer. For the next time, do some self-research FIRST (google, bing, etc) and learn few elisp basics. Try implementing the solution. And then if you face a problem, you can post a question specific to problem you are facing.

Comment: @kaushalmodi
I cannot find any statement on the site to the effect that ‘elisp snippets are not catered to’. ‘How to do X in Emacs’ and ‘Programming in Emacs-lisp’ are  defined as On Topic in the help centre.
http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CharleyRamm The question requested a full custom solution. IMO a good question would be where you tried solving that problem yourself, looked up on how to solve it, discovered `re-backward-regexp` in the process, and let's say you got stuck while making that regexp search work as you want. This is of course a hypothetical scenario. It's good to see a question that shows what the user tried and what failed specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Below should work. It does not strictly follow your pseudo-code but I have put in your pseudo code as comments in-between so that you can get a rough idea of how elisp correlates to that.

```el
(defun my/return-time-diff-frac-hours ()
  (interactive)
  (let (begin-hh begin-mm end-hh end-mm diff)
    (save-excursion
      ;; $end-time      = (search back from pointer for previous instance of HHMM)
      ;; $begin-time    = (search for second previous instance of HHMM)
      (if (re-search-backward (concat "^\\([0-2][0-9]\\)\\([0-5][0-9]\\)"
                                      "\\(?:.*\n\\)"
                                      "\\([0-2][0-9]\\)\\([0-5][0-9]\\)"
                                      "\\(.*\n\\)"
                                      ) nil :noerror)
          (progn
            ;; $begin-hour    = $begin-time[0,1]
            ;; $begin-minute  = $begin-time[2,3]
            (setq begin-hh (string-to-number (match-string 1))) 
            (setq begin-mm (string-to-number (match-string 2))) 
            ;; $end-hour      = $end-time[0,1]
            ;; $end-minute    = $end-time[2,3]
            (setq end-hh (string-to-number (match-string 3))) 
            (setq end-mm (string-to-number (match-string 4)))
            ;; $total-hours   = $end-hour - $begin-hour
            ;; $total-minutes = $end-minutes - $begin-minutes
            ;; return $total-hours + ($total-minutes * 0.01666666667)
            (setq diff (/ (- (+ end-mm  ; end minutes
                                (* 60 end-hh))
                             (+ begin-mm ; begin minutes
                                (* 60 begin-hh)))
                          60.0)))
        (message "Unable to find time strings on consecutive lines.")))
    (when diff
      (insert (number-to-string diff)))))
```

1. Paste the above code in the *scratch* buffer and do `M-x eval-buffer`.
2. Place the cursor at the beginning of 3rd line as in your example and call `M-x my/return-time-diff-frac-hours`.

Comment: -1: I don't think that an answer is the right place to lecture people about what this is supposed to be for or not.  We have flags, close votes and comments for that.

Comment: @lunaryorn You're correct. Fixed.

Comment: This is wonderful. I had to look up progn, save-excursion and match-string. It also took me a while to understand the structure of the math at the end converting minutes to hours.

Comment: This has been a very helpful, functional starting point with Emacs Lisp, and solves a problem I have every day.